# Mongoose create new data with incremented index-like field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What I want to do:
Whenever I add a new item to the collection (in my case a `game`), it will have a incremented "index"-like value (in my case I'm naming it `index` too).

My games collection should looks like:

```
[
  { "index":0, ... data }
  { "index":1, ... data }
  { "index":2, ... data }
]
```

The term is so hard to search. I always end up with:

- `$inc` for `update`. Not this, I want to have incremented number on `create`.
- Schema.index does look like what I want, but somehow it doesn't work at all:

```js
const gameModel = new Schema({
  index: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  players: [{
    name: String,
    score: Number
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'date'
  }
});

gameModel.index({
  index: 1
});
```

With this I always get index: 0. If I turn off default no index is created.

What do I do now? (I would prefer to keep the _id intact)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a npm package named [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment) which provides this functionality. It is also very easy and well documented